# How to replace null into 0 in a complex query

Tags: sql, null, replace

I would like to replace the total value to 0 when it is null

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(location),  (
    SELECT  Count(a.location) as total
    FROM table_fo a   
    LEFT JOIN  table_info b ON a.TRADEID = b.TRADEID AND   a.asofdate = b.asofdate
    WHERE (b.TERMSTATUS <> 'TRAN' OR b.TERMSTATUS is NULL)  AND b.asofdate = '20110105' AND a.location = pfo.location
 GROUP BY a.LOCATION  
)   AS total   
FROM table_fo  pfo
WHERE asofdate = '20110105';
```

Comment: You can use the ISNULL function.

ISNULL(columnName, 0)

Comment: First of all tell us what database model you use. Secondly I don't think your query is valid. The sub-select should return only one value, but this will happen only when you have one location. Thirdly I don't think Count ever returns NULL (at least for MySQL it doesn't).

Comment: @dparker - you should post that as an answer.  That was going to be my answer, but I wouldn't feel right, seeing as how you beat me to it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ISNULL function.

Here is how you will use the function (for SQL Server).

```
ISNULL(columnName, 0)
```

Comment: The name of the function you were thinking of is `IFNULL`. `ISNULL` is something else.

Comment: @Alin - In SQL Server at least `ISNULL` acts like `coalesce`.

Comment: @Martin Hmm... Didn't expect that. I added that it's for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @Alin.

In SQL Server one can use coalesce for multiple columns, like @Will mentioned, where as the ISNULL function, only takes two arguments.

Comment: I'm familiar with `COALESCE` and understood what `ISNULL` does. What confused me was that in MySQL there is an `IFNULL` function that is identical with the `ISNULL` from SQL Server. And `ISNULL` is an operator for checking if something is `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to replace the total
>   value to 0 when it is null

This is an impossible situation because:

*The COUNT function always returns an integer. The result cannot be NULL!*

As for coalescing an expression to a certain default in case it is NULL there are functions that do this in all major databases (ex.: `COALESCE`, `NVL`, `ISNULL`, `IFNULL`). The typical use is

```
FUNCTION_NAME(ExpressionThatMayBeNULL, DefaultWhenNull)
```

For specifics you should consult you database manufacturers documentation (you can find it online).

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE` will do this in PL/SQL (Oracle) and T-SQL (SQL Server)

Syntax is `COALESCE(field1, field2[, fieldN])` - it will select the first column from the left to have a non-null value.

Modifying the query you had:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(location),  COALESCE((
    SELECT  Count(a.location) as total
    FROM table_fo a   
    LEFT JOIN  table_info b ON a.TRADEID = b.TRADEID AND   a.asofdate = b.asofdate
    WHERE (b.TERMSTATUS <> 'TRAN' OR b.TERMSTATUS is NULL)  AND b.asofdate = '20110105' AND a.location = pfo.location
 GROUP BY a.LOCATION  
),0)   AS total   
FROM table_fo  pfo
WHERE asofdate = '20110105';
```

Answer (score 2):

As dparker said, ISNULL(...) will work for some types of sql, though the name of the function can vary among database providers.

The function in IBM DB2 is called COALESCE(...), and in Oracle SQL it is NVL(...) for example.

This may be usefull

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL server, the following are the 3 ways that can be used to replace a null with any user defined substitute value. 
1. ISNULL
2. COALESCE
3. CASE

This question is also asked in one of the interviews I attended. Here is the link for an article with examples. By the way, there's also a video on the same in this article.

[Different ways to replace NULLS in SQL Server](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/08/different-ways-to-replace-null-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

What DB system are you using?

- SQL-Server, MySQL: `IFNULL(value, 0)`
- Oracle: `NVL(value, 0)`
- PostgreSQL: `COALESCE(value, 0)`